# Rails to_s Mechanics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, special-characters

Hey guys this has been tripping me up quite a bit. So here is the general problem:

I am writing an application that requires users to enter their Summoner Names from league of legends. I do a pretty simple data scrape of a match and enter the data into my database. Unfortunately I am having some errors registering users with "special characters".

For this example I will use one problem user: RIÇK

As you can see RICK != RIÇK. So when I do the data scrub from the site I get the correct value which I push onto an array for later use.

Once I need the player names I pull from the array as follows: (player_names is the array)

```
@temp_player = User.find_by_username(player_names[i].to_s)
```

The problem is the users with any special characters are not being pulled. Should I not be using find_by? Is to_s changing my original values? I am really quite lost on what to do and would greatly appreciate any help / advice.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: i believe it's not `to_s` but the DB charset;

Comment: @ted im a little confused by the response. Is DB charset referring to the Database storage mode? If so I am looking at the backend of the site and I am seeing that each of those users names are being displayed properly with their special characters.

Comment: Why are you calling `.to_s`? Are you not pushing strings onto the `player_names` array?

Comment: I am using the following to push onto the array. player_names.push(line.chomp.tr("[U]", "")[1..-1]. should I be forcing the value to_s at this point rather than later? not sure why this would effect the outcome.

Comment: and `User.find_by_username('RIÇK')` returns a user?

Comment: Yeah the user is definitely being found when I run the find command in console. :/

Comment: `puts player_names.inspect` so you can see what's in that array and traceback; you may also `puts 'RIÇK'.to_s.inspect` to find out whether the string will be corrupted (that i doubt about)

Comment: wow shit. Did some research and it looks like RIÇK is being pulled as RI&Ccedil;K. Any ideas?

Comment: Alright i think it may have something to do with the scraper im using but still not sure. Im using scrapi to get all the information so maybe there is a setting to allow for special characters. or change the character set

Comment: Ç == &Ccedil; in terms of ISO 8859-1 characters; So mind the charset wherever it's considered to.

Comment: knowing the character set. Would it be possible to have it modify directly into its string format? Since its getting passed as plain text (meaning all those characters are being read)

Comment: You might find this related reading on character encoding helpful: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank Brian Kung for the link to the following: [joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) It does a great job giving the bare minimum a programmer truly needs to understand.

For my particular issue I had used a HTML scraper to get the contents but which kept HTML entries throughout. When using these with my SQL lookups it was obvious that things were not being found. In order to fix this I used the HTMLEntities Gem to decode the text as follows (as soon as I put the into the array originally):

```
requires 'RubyGems' #without this cannot include htmlentries as a gem
requires 'HTMLEntries' 

coder = HTMLEntries.new

line = '&amp;lt;'
player_names.push(coder.decode(line))
```

**The Takeaway**

When working with text and if running into errors I would strongly recommend tracing the strings you are working with to the origin and truly understanding what encoding is being used in each process. By doing this you can easily find where things are going wrong.